# How to do image processing with Phonegap in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile, image-processing, cordova

I want to know how to manipulate pixels like what we can do within the C# code in JavaScript with Phonegap lib.

I am not sure whether it is possible. So far what I have found is nothing related to image processing in the Phonegap library.(It does provide Image, Capture helper to do something, but it's not enough.)

When I say manipulate pixels it's not about the simple methods like crop, resize, rotate etc. it should down to the level of having access of individual pixels in an image so more complicated computation can be conducted.

Thank you.

PS:
guys thank you for leaving "-1", please give your reasons at the same time. thx

Comment: Since is javascript, you would do it the same you would do it on a browser: using <canvas>

Comment: @chris thx, I found canvas helpful.

Comment: @chris-l Hi your comment is the closest one, please post it as an answer and I will mark it as my answer. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since is javascript, is done the same you would do it on a browser: using `<canvas>`

Here is [fastCanvas](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas), a phonegap plugin for using it. I haven't use it, but I hope is actually useful.

Answer (score 3):

@chris is right. Because you're running Javacript you can use anyway JS libraries that you used on desktop.
For example, I use CamanJS (http://camanjs.com/) to apply some filters in my Phonegap App. It's easy to use and works well.
But don't forget that you are running JS on a mobile device. Mobile devices haven't the same computing power as desktops...

Comment: Hi Aliassse,  are those libraries powerful enough to handle complicated image processing? And thank you for providing a JS image library.

Comment: Want do you mean by "powerful enough to handle complicated image processing" ? What do you want to do with these libraries ?

Comment: Hi Aliassse, please have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_processing  cheers

Comment: I guess what I wanted to ask was how to do the image convolution, erosion, dilation, etc. all these kind of operations which I used to think that they can only be done by manipulating pixels by using C++. Thank you for your reply.